# How to specify application is for large screen devices

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I have developed an android application on 2.2 and I want to release it in android market but my application is only for large screen device so is there any way that I can specify the screen size while publishing application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer it is on android site [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html)

Answer (score 6):

Include this chunk of code inside your AndroidManifest file:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="false" android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

This should help.

Comment: As per the android documentation 

If your application does not support small screens, then there isn't much the system can do to make the application work well on a smaller screen, so external services (such as Android Market) should not allow users to install the application on such screens.


Do u have any idea how android market will block user from downloading the application in small screen devices.

Comment: @Brijesh Masrani, I don't know the complete scheme, but you can be sure, that if your app does not support small screens, a user with a small screened device won't be able to install your app.

Comment: Hi Egor It worked ..... ya you are right it will not show application on unsupported device.

Thanks.